# To Filter json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In the below code i have two jsons which i have to filter json based on json data/value.

Master Json:

```
    var set1 =[{"LevelID":"1","levelname":"Level1",,"levelType":"TypeA"},
    {"LevelID":"2","levelname":"Level2",,"levelType":"TypeB"},
    {"LevelID":"3","levelname":"Level3",,"levelType":"TypeC"},
    {"LevelID":"4","levelname":"Level4",,"levelType":"TypeD"}
    ];
```

Data Json:

```
    var set2 =[{"LevelID":"1"},{"LevelID":"2"}];

    var Commaseparated="TypeA","TypeD";
```

Here i want to pass Data json and commaseparated to Master json and filter and get the filtered data that should match with levelID and Commaseparated.

Expected result:

```
    var set3 =[{"LevelID":"1","levelname":"Level1","levelType":"TypeA"}];
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective here is to help fix **your code**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best way, but here's one way you could start going that direction.

```js
var master = [{"LevelID":"1","levelname":"Level1","levelType":"TypeA"},
    {"LevelID":"2","levelname":"Level2","levelType":"TypeB"},
    {"LevelID":"3","levelname":"Level3","levelType":"TypeC"},
    {"LevelID":"4","levelname":"Level4","levelType":"TypeD"}
    ];

var set2 = [{
  "LevelID": "1"
}, {
  "LevelID": "2"
}];

var Commaseparated = ["TypeA", "TypeD"];

const set3 = master.filter(item => {
  return set2.find(item2 => item.LevelID === item2.LevelID)
}).filter(exclude => Commaseparated.indexOf(exclude.levelType) > -1);

/*
const set3 = set2.map(item => {
  item.levelname = Commaseparated[item.LevelID - 1];
  return item;
});
*/

console.log(set3);
```

Comment: I have to compare with set 2 with set 1 and filter

Comment: Ah, I missed the set1 as it was unformatted originally. So the commaseparated is completely irrelevant right?  You only want to filter set1 by the levelid in set2?

Comment: Yes that is the expected

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: with Commaseparated we have to check with level type and filter

Comment: So you want to first filter by level ID but exclude anything that's not in commaseparated?

Comment: Only [{"LevelID":"1","levelname":"Level1","levelType":"TypeA"}] to be the final json to get

Comment: Done. It's getting nasty but it answers the question.

Comment: We have "TypeA"  present in const 3 that to be display

Comment: This answer produced your desired result but you unaccepted it. I don't see any const 3 or any TypeA other than for levelId 1. I would delete this question and ask a new one with a [mcve] so you can get the response you are looking for.